# MySQL “Show table status”, auto increment is not providing next value

Tags: mysql

I'm recently installed a new server with a newer MySQL release (from 8.0.13 to 8.0.16) and I have a different behavior while retrieving the next auto increment value of my table.

I was initially using

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE `Name` = 'user';
```

in my previous server it was working perfectly, I was able to retrieve the next auto increment value for the next record, but with the new server the same command is not working properly, the value displayed for auto_increment is not the next one

I have found a post mentioning that it might be due to the cache of the statistics table but on both servers I have

```
show variables like 'information_schema_stats_expiry';
+---------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                   | Value |
+---------------------------------+-------+
| information_schema_stats_expiry | 86400 |
+---------------------------------+-------+
```

There is also a solution by disabling the cache of this table by using the command

```
SET PERSIST information_schema_stats_expiry = 0
```

but I have two questions:

- first: where do I set this information_schema_stats_expiry ? I'm not able to launch this command on a SQL command line, neither in the mysql config file
- second: If we disable the cache of this table, is there any issue with the overall database performance ?

Comment: Do you see the correct auto increment with `SHOW CREATE TABLE user`?

Comment: I can see the create table function with my id set as NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: What does it say at the end in `AUTO_INCREMENT =`?

Comment: nothing, just CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,....

Comment: at the end I have ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=82 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 and the command SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE `Name` = 'user'; give me 79.....

Comment: That's the part I was asking about, I wanted to know if it showed a different number.

Comment: Since that seems to show the correct value, can you use that instead of `SHOW TABLE STATUS`?

Comment: yes but how do I extract this value ? (my server is developed in Java)

Comment: How about querying `information_schema.tables`?

Comment: Same thing, command SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "myapp" AND TABLE_NAME = "user"; give me 79.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this changed when you upgraded from 8.0.13 to 8.0.16. The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_information_schema_stats_expiry) says that this variable was added in 8.0.3.

This can be set as a session variable, so you could set it to `0` just in the session that needs to fetch the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value, and it should bypass the cache. But it won't affect other sessions, so should have minimal overall impact on performance.

```
SET information_schema_stats_expiry = 0;
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE `Name` = 'user';
```